# __getattribute__ getting attributes from custom dict

Tags: python, oop, getattribute

how to get attributes from the instance «custome» dict (here it is `d_new`), rather than instance «standard» `__dict__` ?

I am trying to use `__getattribute__` for this purpose.

```
class FTr:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d_new = {}

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        # if hasattr(something, 'd_new'):
        #     return 
        # else:
            return super().__getattribute__(name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):        
        if hasattr(self, 'd_new'):
            self.d_new[name] = value
        else:
            self.__dict__[name] = value
        
    def base(self, val):
        return getattr(self, val)


class Point(FTr):
    fields = ('x', 'y', 'z')

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x, self.y, self.z = x, y, z
        super().__init__()


p = Point(1, 2, 3)
print(p.base('x'))
p.x = 4
print(p.base('x'))
print(p.x)
```

The result I would like to have is (the last output `4` not `1`):

```
#1
#1
#4
```

Answer (score 1):

`__getattribute__` is a bit tricky to implement, because it is used for *any* attribute access, even that access occur from inside itself - so, you can't just use `self.d_new` in that code.

By calling the original `__getattribute__`, however, that is feasible.

```
class FTr:
    fields = ()
    def __init__(self):
        self.d_new = {}
        for name in self.__class__.fields:
            self.d_new[name] = None

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        try:
            namespace = super().__getattribute__("d_new")
        except AttributeError:
            return {}
        if name in namespace:
            return namespace[name]
        return super().__getattribute__(name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):        
        if name in self.d_new:
            self.d_new[name] = value
            return
        return super().__setattr__(name, value)


class Point(FTr):
    fields = ('x', 'y', 'z')

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        super().__init__()
        self.x, self.y, self.z = x, y, z
```

Comment: Thank you for comment. The code crushes...
```----> 9     namespace = super().__getattribute__('d_new')```

Comment: Well - it is tricky as I said.  :-) it turns out `__setattr__` will try to read `d_new`  before setting any attribute, including `d_new` itself. 
Also, in the subclass, `__init__` of the superclass must run before any other lines (I fixed that as well)

Comment: Oops. Incorrect output:
1
4
4
rater than
1
1
4

Comment: Well - I thought you want to get ordinary attributes to be contained in another, custom dictionary, and this is the code for that. If you want custom attributes to only be setable and readable  by calling special methods, none of this is needed, just keep an ordinary dictionary as your custom namespace and use your getter and setter methods to reach that namespace.  "1 4 4" is the output I would be expecting given you example.